# Truffle not working after install using npm

Tags: truffle, nodejs, npm

I just tried to install truffle using npm. I followed the documentation and did
npm -g install truffle

However, after that, when I try to do anything (such as just run `truffle` or `truffle --version`), I get the error

```
/home/jonathan/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/625.bundled.js:95862
  } catch {
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.__webpack_require__.f.require (/home/jonathan/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:613:28)
```

my npm version is 6.14.8, nodejs version 8.10.0. running `which truffle` gives

```
/home/jonathan/.npm-global/bin/truffle
```

I am at a complete loss, does anyone know how to fix this? Im also quite the beginner when using npm, only use it for ethereum related things.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well, the problem is the nodejs version.
Updating to v15.11.0 and reinstalling Truffle should fix it.

Comment: Former Truffle team member here - this is likely correct. Node 8 is super old. Also if you're not using NVM or one of its sister projects to manage your node versions, I highly recommend it. https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm